# Is it possible to use the slider step form Element Without the Slider?

Tags: jquery-mobile, slider

I want to use jQuery Mobile's Slider step element without the need for a slider. Is this possible while still maintaining full functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this works for you. Set `div.ui-slider{display:none;}​​`. See fiddle for demo http://jsfiddle.net/codaniel/pt4uN/3/

Update: Improved answer according to specifications. Updated fiddle revision.

Comment: Close. I just want the stepper. I don't want the slide bar at all.

Comment: Oh ok yeah i updated my answer for you. I thought you were talking about the slide handle in particular for some reason. If that is not right I may need you to draw a picture for me hehe.